# Is it safe to directly delete head files from .git?

Tags: git, branch

I had my first look at branching and ended up creating some stupid branches that I have messed up. I wish to remove them. I can see them here in the file structure like below.

[image: heads files]

So I can see all my heads there and what I would like to know is whether I can just delete them there. It feels like a really dirty way of dealing with the mistakes I made with these but I need to get back to just being on the master branch as soon as possible.

Are there any dangerous implications that come with deleting these directly?

Comment: git branch -D would be recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's safe to delete the branch's head directly but you can safely use the `-D` option:

```
git branch -D <branch_to_delete>
```

Comment: Perfect, simple, clean and to the point. thanks geckon, I don't have to go through the sacrilege of deleting files in the file explorer.

Comment: @JoeLloyd, I'm glad I could help. Can you mark it as answer then? :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I had to wait the certain time before accepting.
thanks again.